# Error while working with the inet radio modules

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have two problems while working with the the inet radio modules. I think they are somehow interrelated.

---

Problem 1

When I am using subscribe function in my MAC layer

```
radioModule->subscribe(IRadio::radioModeChangedSignal, this);
radioModule->subscribe(IRadio::transmissionStateChangedSignal, this);
```

I get this error

```
Error in module (inet::physicallayer::Radio) MyNetwork.sta[0].nic[0].radio(id=19) during network initialization: inet::MyMac: Unsupported signal data type long for signal radioModeChanged (id=34).
```

---

Problem 2

My receiver module has a problem with these functions in inet.physicallayer.common.RadioMedium.cc

```
const IListening *listening = receiverRadio->getReceiver()->createListening(receiverRadio, arrival->getStartTime(), arrival->getEndTime(), arrival->getStartPosition(), arrival->getEndPosition());
[...]
communicationCache->setCachedListening(receiverRadio, transmission, listening);
```

I get this error

```
<!> Error in module (inet::physicallayer::Radio) MyNetwork.sta[0].nic[0].radio (id=19) at event #33, t=2: ASSERT: condition shareCount == 0 false in function parsimUnpack, cpacket.cc line 146.
```

Comment: Which versions of `OMNeT++` and `INET` do you use?

Comment: OMNeT++ Version 5.0, Build 160414-aa4629c
INET Version 3.4.0-bb8393f

Answer (score 0):

According Problem 1: you have to override the method 
`virtual void receiveSignal(cComponent *source, simsignal_t signalID, long l, cObject *details)` 
in your `MyMac` class. Without this method a simple module doesn't know what to do with received signal, therefore it throws an error.

Problem 2 is connected with a packet handling, maybe decapsulation. The presented code is not the source of it. Set `debug-on-errors=true` in your `omnetpp.ini` then run simulation in debug mode. You should see the place in your code which causes this error.